# Are all the $x$ satisfying $x+ax^2+x^4+x^{2q}=0$ belonging to $\mathbb{F}_{q}$? Here, $q=2^m$, $a\in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, $x\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $q=2^m$ for some positive integer. Let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be the finite field with $q$ elements. Let $a\in \mathbb{F}_{q}$. Let $x\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$. If $x$ satisfies the following equation:
$$x+ax^2+x^4+x^{2q}=0,$$
then numerical experiments indicate that $x$ must belong to $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. I tried but I can not give a proof. Or: I want to show that if $x\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ with $x\neq 0$, then there are no such solutions $x$ satisfying $x+x^q+x^{q^2}=0$ to the above equation. But, I also can not give a proof.
Would you like to help me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140267/discussion-on-question-by-zheng-lijing-are-all-the-x-satisfying-xax2x4x).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry about leaving that chain of comments around. Many users have criticized this tendency of mine, and I try to learn away from it. Anyway, I wanted to leave the key contents of the comment exchange visible. For my own benefit as well as that of the future readers of this thread. I think Zheng Lijing and I made serious progress, so I collected the pieces into an answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No problem, really---the comments are still there, just in chat. I'll put a ChatJax link in there for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

The question proved to be tough. No solution yet, but non-trivial progress was made in the comments. As those were relocated into a chat room I am posting a summary of the contributions.

---

Here $q=2^m$, and we live in the field $F=\Bbb{F}_q$ as well as its cubic extension $E=\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$. There is a parameter $a\in F$, and the question is about the zeros of the polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^{2q}+x^4+ax^2+x\in F[x].
$$
More precisely, Zheng Lijing checked out several cases and formulated the conjecture stating that every zero $\alpha\in E$ of $f(x)$ is actually an element $F$.

A crucial fact is that all the terms in $f$ have degrees that are powers of two. In other words, $f$ is an *additive polynomial*, i.e. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. This follows from Freshman's dream, or the fact that squaring is an automorphism of the fields. Another basic fact is that the elements of $F$ satisfy the equation $x^q=x$, and the elements of $E$ the corresponding equation $x^{q^3}=x$.

A trick of the trade in studying solutions of an additive polynomial like $f$ in $E$ is to try and find $\gcd(f(x),x^{q^3}-x)$. Taking advantage of the additive structure we can, instead of the usual Euclid's algoritm of using the multiples $x^\ell f$, we utilize the easily computable powers $f^{2^\ell}$. In particular, every zero $\alpha\in E$ of $f(x)$ is also a zero of
$$
f_2:=f^{2q}=x^{4q^2}+x^{8q}+a^{2q}x^{4q}+x^{2q}=x^{4q^2}+x^{8q}+a^2x^{4q}+x^{2q}
$$
as well as
$$
f_3:=f^{4q^2}=x^{8q^3}+x^{16q^2}+a^4x^{8q^2}+x^{4q^2}.
$$
Subtracting appropriate multiples of first $f_2^{2^j}, j=0,1,2,$ and then multiples of $f^{2^i}$ allows us to eliminate all the high degree terms from $f_3$ except for the term $x^{8q^3}$. But, as we are searching for roots satisfying $\alpha^{q^3}=\alpha$, that remaining term can also be replaced with $x^8$. We have arrived at the

**Lemma 1.** Every root $\alpha \in E$ of $f(x)$ is also a root of the degree $64$ polynomial
$$
P(x)=x^{64}+\left(a^{16}+a^8+a^4\right) x^{32}+\left(a^{16}+a^{12}+a^8+1\right)
   x^{16}+\left(a^{12}+a^8+a^2+1\right)
   x^8+\left(a^8+a^6+a^4+1\right) x^4++ \left(a^4+a^2+a\right) x^2+x.
$$

Temporarily treating $a$ as an algebraically independent variable, using the Gröbner basis algorithms of Mathematica I checked in the cases $m\le 7$ that the polynomial
$$
L(x)=x^4+(a+1)x^2+x
$$
belongs to the ideal $I_m=\langle a^q+a, x^{q^3}+x, f(x)\rangle\subset \Bbb{F}_2[x,a]$. It is not unnatural to conjecture that this might always be the case. The importance of this is the following

**Lemma 2.** If $L(x)\in I_m$, the main conjecture holds for $q=2^m$.

**Proof.** If $L(x)\in I$, then every zero $\alpha\in E$ of $f(x)$ is also a zero of $L(x)$. As $f(x)-L(x)=(x^q+x)^2$, it follows that $\alpha$ is also a zero of $x^q+x$. In other words, $\alpha\in F$. QED.

One of the tools in dealing with additive polynomials is symbolic factorization, i.e. writing it as a composition of lower degree additive polynomials. Given all of the above it is natural to ask whether $L(x)$ is a symbolic factor of $P(x)$. It turns out to always be the case as we have

**Observation 1.** With the polynomial
$$Q(x):=x^{16} + (a^8 + a^4 + 1) x^8 + (a^8 + a^4 + 1) x^4 + (a^4 + a^2 + 
    1) x^2 + x\in F[x]$$
we have
$$P(x)=Q(L(x)).$$

It follows that every zero of $L(x)$ in $E$ is also a zero of $P(x)$, but this does not prove the main conjecture.

I have been unable to further factor $Q(x)$ symbolically. I don't know what that means :-). However, Zheng Lijing managed to factor $P(x)$ further.

**Observation 2.** The polynomial $P(x)/L(x)$ has the factors.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(x^5 + x^3 + xa^2 + xa + 1),\\ 
&(x^5 + x^3a + x^2 + xa + 1),\\
&(x^5 + x^3a + x^3 + x^2 + xa + x + 1),\\
&(x^{15} + x^{11}a + x^{11} + x^{10} + x^9a^2 + x^9 + x^7a^4 + x^7a^3 + x^7a + x^7 + x^6a^2 + x^6 + x^5a^4 + x^5a +x^5 + x^4 + x^3a^4 + x^3a^3 + x^3 + x^2a^2 + xa^4 + xa^2 + x*a + x + 1),\\
&(x^{15} + x^{13} + x^9a + x^8 + x^7a^4 + x^5a^4 + x^5a^3 + x^5 +x^4a^2 + x^3a + x^2 + xa^2 + xa + x + 1),\\
&(x^{15} + x^{13}a + x^{12} + x^{11}a^2 + x^9a^3 + x^8a^2 + x^7a^2 +x^5a^3 + x^5a + x^5 + x^4a^2 + x^4 + x^3a + x^3+ x^2 + xa + 1).
\end{aligned}$$

A few special cases: When $a$ is an element of the prime field $\Bbb{F}_2$, the polynomial $f(x)$ is linearized, and we have the machinery of conventional associates of linearized polynomials. The conventional associates can be handled with the usual Euclid's algorithm, and I have these observations (unchecked)

**Observation 3.**

- If $a=1$, then the zeros of $f(x)$ in $E$ are exactly the elements in
  $\Bbb{F}_4\cap E$. Because $[E:F]=3$, the main conjecture holds in
  this case.
- If $a=0$, then the zeros of $f(x)$ in $E$ are exactly the roots of $x^4+x^2+x$
  in $\Bbb{F}_8\cap F$. The main conjecture holds in this case also.

So in the two special cases above we know that the zeros of $f$ in $E$ are exactly the zeros of $L(x)$ in $F$.